# What programming language is the easiest to write a compiler for?

Tags: compiler-construction, programming-languages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good languages to write a compiler for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484328/good-languages-to-write-a-compiler-for)

I would like to know if there are any programming languages or byte code definitions (machine independent) that are extremely simple to write a compiler/parser for. The language itself should ideally be well-specified and powerful, and does not need to be easy to use. Is there such a programming language?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484328/good-languages-to-write-a-compiler-for

Answer (score 2):

Any *assembly language* would be easy to write a compiler for, since each statement translates directly into a machine instruction.  (Though it would more accurately be called an assembler, rather than a compiler.)

For platform independent bytecode options of the same, you could look into:

- [Common Intermediate Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) - [standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm)
- [Java Assembly Language](http://tinf2.vub.ac.be/~dvermeir/courses/compilers/javaa/jasm.html) (Not well specified)

Comment: Ah, yes, you are correct of course... I forgot to specify that it should be machine independent. Otherwise, I guess machine code would be even easier, since it doesn't need compiling at all. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: That's hardly a compiler. There's a reason they call it assembler.

Comment: @delnan And yet other than the word compiler it ostensibly met all the criteria for what the OP was looking for.  Free your mind.

Answer (score 1):

Scheme is pretty close. [Writing a scheme interpreter  tutorial](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours)

Another interesting choice would be a Z-code (used in many old text adventure games) machine. This bytecode format is well documented, and it would probably be a really interesting project. The wide availability of existing non-trivial Z-code files to play on it, err, test it with, is another upside. How cool would it be to run Zork on an interpreter you wrote?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this exactly fits your requirement, but I hope you can appreciate this recommendation: http://lolcode.com/

Answer (score -3):

Java? 'Simple' is quite subjective really

Comment: According to Martin Odersky, there are about three people in the world who understand Wildcards. And from the tone of the email, I got the impression that Odersky does not consider himself among those three people. Now, if the person who designed and implemented Java Generics apparently doesn't even understand them himself, how is someone who is just starting to learn about compilers supposed to implement Java? I mean, Wildcards are only a small part of Generics, Generics are only a small part of the type system, and the type system is only a small part of Java. If even a small part of …

Comment: … a small part of a small part of Java is only understood by three people, how many people do you think are there who understand Java, and how likely do you think it is the OP is among those people? The Java Language Specification is well over 700 pages, and that is not even including the syntax and the appendices.

Comment: @JörgWMittag a) this answer is over 8 years old. b) 700 pages seems a lot, but is it when compared to other languages? c) The JVM is a stack-based machine, generating the bytecode for it is very straightforward, even I've done it.

Comment: "700 pages seems a lot, but is it when compared to other languages?" – It is less than C++ but for example more than 3 times the size of the Scala Language Specification. The Wirth family of languages is about ~40 pages each, I believe. (Pascal was the most complex one, and each successor had a smaller spec. The latest in the series is Component Pascal which weighs in at 30 pages.) I think Eiffel is a better comparison since it has everything Java has (and more) and its specification is written in a similar style. Eiffel's spec weighs in at 163 pages.

Comment: "The JVM is a stack-based machine, generating the bytecode for it is very straightforward, even I've done it." – What does the JVM have to do with that? You didn't say the JVM was simple (I would somewhat agree), you said Java was simple, and I disagree with that. It may be simpl**er** than e.g. C++, but that is more because C++ is insanely complex (it is said that no single person on the planet understands C++) and not because Java is simple. I guess one of the problems with Java is that there is no "thread" that goes through its design, it is just exceptions piled on corner cases with …

Comment: … special features bolted on to another exception.